# Настройка сборки и деплоя

Tags: npm, angular

Есть `angular` проект - обычная вебморда. Есть сервер сборки `teamcity`. На сервере есть два агента, оба агента на одной машине. На машине с агентами уже установлен `npm` и глобально загружены `angular-cli` пакеты.

Интересует как сконфигурировать сборку и деплой.

По факту у нас из `CVS` берутся исходники, как и всегда, и происходит несколько билдстепов :

1) подгрузка необходимых пакетов, в `CVS` их мы не храним
2) билд с необходимо конфигурацией

А вот затем, когда все уже собрано как мне это деплоить на другую машину, и как она должна быть сконфигурированна?

по факту тот же самый `npm` и `algular-cli`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам отвечу на свой вопрос.

1) нам необходимо на билдагенте и на тимсити поставить [плагин TeamCity.Node](https://github.com/jonnyzzz/TeamCity.Node)

2) поставить глобально пакеты angular на машину где билд агент.

```
npm install -g angular-cli
```

3) на тимсити создать наш проект, **главное чтобы в исходниках не было `node_modules` папки!** добавьте ее в git.ignore - она весит очень много, порядка 200+ мб

4) добавить билдстеп, где `Runner type: Node.js NPM`
в поле `npm commands` вписать :

```
update 

build
```

Маленькое лирическое отступление если у вас есть конфигурации под разные стейджинги

> Допустим если у вас есть различные `environment` конфигурации,
>   `environment.qa.ts`/`environment.dev.ts`
>
> и вы хотите билдить исходя из конфигурации так же как и локально
>   командой `ng build --configuration=dev.` то вам необходимо добавить
>   скрипты в файле `angular.json` в вашем проекте.
>
> Примерно так :
>
> ```
>  "scripts": {
>     "ng": "ng",
>     "start": "ng serve",
>     "build": "ng build",
>     "build_dev": "ng build --configuration=dev",
>     "build_qa": "ng build --configuration=qa",
>     "build_prod": "ng build --configuration=prod",
>     "test": "ng test",
>     "lint": "ng lint",
>     "e2e": "ng e2e"
>   },
> ```
>
> И тогда команда в билдстепе вместо `build` будет, например, `run build_dev`

5) У меня все хостится на `IIS` и поэтому я свой сбилдженный `dist` кидаю в папку на шару куда и смотрит мой `IIS` - банальным xcopy